# How to stretch image to fill div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to fill a div with a image that changes every 3 seconds. I'm using this JavaScript code:

```
        function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "image1.jpg";
      images[1] = "image2.png";
      images[2] = "image3.png";
```

The HTML code looks like this.

```
<div id="banner">
    <img id="img"/>
    </div>
```

How can I stretch/crop these images to make them fill the entire div?

```
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    height:35%;
    background-color:yellow;
    left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
}
img {

}
```

Comment: What about CSS?

Comment: CSS object-fit might do : a CSS example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aBqOLa (resize window) see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is better for that, because resizing the screen is handled automatically.

1. If you don't need to support IE, use [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).
2. If you need to support IE, place the images as the `<div>` background, and use [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) with [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

---

**Using `object-fit: cover`**

```js
var images = [
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/9d/3d/929d3d9f76f406b5ac6020323d2d32dc.jpg",
    "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg"
  ],
  x = -1;

function displayNextImage() {
  x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}

function displayPreviousImage() {
  x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}

function startTimer() {
  displayNextImage();
  setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
}

startTimer();
```

```css
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    height:35%;
    background-color:yellow;
    left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
}
#img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img id="img" />
</div>
```

---

**Using `background-size: cover`**

```js
var images = [
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/9d/3d/929d3d9f76f406b5ac6020323d2d32dc.jpg",
    "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg"
  ],
  x = -1;

function displayNextImage() {
  x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
  document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[x] + ")";
}

function displayPreviousImage() {
  x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
  document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[x] + ")";
}

function startTimer() {
  displayNextImage();
  setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
}

startTimer();
```

```css
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    height:35%;
    background-color:yellow;
    left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: Let me make it even more weird: It does work on Edge. All hail the goat browser ofcourse

Comment: Thanks that would be great

Comment: I swear to Jon Skeet my chrome is f*cked. It just repeats the same image. even if I use the background-repeat property. While Edge displays it correctly

Comment: It was my adblocker. I fixed it now. You're a legend Ori :)